# How to Set Maven Parameters in OpenShift

Tags: openshift

I'm completely new to OpenShift and so far ran in hundreds of bugs while trying to create my first application. Now I want to configure Maven to use my own goals. So far I tried:

- adding a Jenkins and configuring the Maven Build - the Jenkins didn't take up the changes and finally stopped building altogether
- adding a file *.openshift/action_hook/pre_build* with the content `export MAVEN_ARGS="clean package -Popenshift"` as explained [here](https://www.openshift.com/developers/deploying-and-building-applications)
- adding a file *.openshift/action_hook/build* with the content `mvn clean package -Popenshift` as explained [there](http://blog-judcon.rhcloud.com/?p=16)

Evidently, the documentation is somewhat obsolete... so what is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get the Jenkins to build with my goals. The misconception was that it would use the configured Maven goals INSTEAD of the default ones, when it would just use them additionally (he never had to, since the shell script failed). So deleting the script and adding a custom Maven build works.