# OpenShift - How to Build On Windows Server

Tags: openshift

I ran into [a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710140/failed-to-resolve-target-definition-on-openshift) deploying my very first application which I strongly believe can be attributed to the Linux server. So how can I change the build to run on a Windows host?

On Jenkins, there is an ominous "platform" field, but I inserted dozens of permutations of "win", "windows", "x86", "64" and it doesn't complain, but doesn't use another server OS either.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You would be better trying to ask about the Linux bug.

Comment: I already did. Since I can't fix that I have to do the next best thing. So what's this "platform" field for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about OpenShift Online, we do not offer a windows server to do builds on, or run your application on.  If you are trying to run .net code, you would need to use the community Mono cartridge.

Comment: "Unfortunately" I have Java code, so I have to search for another PaaS provider.

Comment: We do support java, we have Tomcat 6/7, JBoss AS 7, JBoss EAP 6.2, and WildFly servers available

Comment: Check [the bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710140/failed-to-resolve-target-definition-on-openshift) out - you might support Java, but your Linux servers don't support the additionally Maven plug-ins I need. Which is a shame, since Tycho is spreading.